# Regex not matching one example of a telephone number

Tags: regex

I have spent time creating a regular expression, but have got to a point where I am struggling to fix one last issue with it.

This regex matches telephone numbers, and it works for following formats:

- 01234 567 890
- 01234 567890
- +441234567890
- (555) 555-1234
- (555)5551234

Regex:

```
/\s*(([+](\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)|0)?(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d){9}|[(](\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)+\s*[)]([-\s]?\d)+)\s*/;
```

But this does not match:

```
441234567890
```

It's the same as one of the examples above, `+441234567890` but without the `+`.

Comment: + is a special character in regex and must be escaped `\s*((\+([-\s]?\d)|0)?(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d){9}|(([-\s]?\d)+\s*)+)\s*`

Comment: @Jens I just realised my refex didn't paste properly. See my updated regex

Comment: Change `[+]` to `[+]?`

Comment: Is the `+` optional in that case?

Comment: @user3783243 yes. BTW although `[+]` is one way to "escape" the plus, the usual way is `\+`

Answer (score 1):

This works for me for all of your examples:

```
/\s*(([+]{0,1}(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)|0)?(\s?\d)([-\s]?\d){9}|[(](\s?\d)([-\s]?\d)+\s*[)]([-\s]?\d)+)\s*/;
```

I've added **{0,1}** after the [+], so that it will match either a single or no + (which could actually also be done by using **[+]?** )

Answer (score 0):

In my case something like this works:

```
^(\d|\+|\()?(\d)+(\s|\))?(\s)?(\d(\s|-)?)+\d$
```